# What causes tea to foam?

Tags: tea, microwave, water, foam

Sometimes my tea has some foam on top. Is the "white" foam caused by denatured proteins in the tea leaves when heated?

And is there a method that I can always get this white foam,  because to me the tea tastes better that way, I love it with foam on it.

Comment: @dbmag9 using the tools available to us, the mod team found no tangible evidence for a spam anchor. The question was in need of some gentle editing though.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find this article discussing the subject and even offering a few ideas for how to get tea foam intentionally:

https://www.dreamycup.com/why-does-tea-foam/

The ideas they shared were:

1. Pour your water from a significant height
2. Shake your tea vigorously in a bottle

I'm not sure if this will result in the same type of foam you enjoy so much, but they're easy methods to try.

Interestingly, they also note that the natural occurrence of tea foam was considered a treasure in ancient China, and a sign of imminent love in England. Some even say it means you're soon to come into money. So you are most definitely not alone in your love of tea foam!

Comment: it work thank you very much :)

Comment: That's great to hear! I'm going to have to give it a try myself and find out what all the rage is about.

Comment: Not a lot of people like green tea I love it with foam on top I don't understand why I do but it just tast a lot better...

Comment: The page you linked to had some good information, but I suspect that you left out an important part: “It isn’t unusual for tea to foam because it contains saponins.
Saponins are chemicals that produce soap-like foam when added to water.”